# How do I ensure that the Number column has values greater than one?

Tags: sql

I have tried adding "HAVING Number>1" However this doesn't work correctly it only outputs 1 row

```
SELECT 
    T.EmployeeID,
    COUNT(*) AS "Number" 
FROM (
    SELECT 
        Skill.Title,
        Skill.SkillID,
        EmployeeSkill.EmployeeID 
   FROM Skill 
   RIGHT JOIN EmployeeSkill ON EmployeeSkill.SkillID = Skill.SkillID
) T
GROUP BY T.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, a tag for the database you are using, and n explanation of what you are trying to do..

Answer (score 0):

I believe it should work if you will use "having count(*)>1" instead of "having number>1"

Answer (score 0):

If you want from the query only the rows where `Number > 1` 
then you need to add a [HAVING](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-having-clause.htm) clause to the statement:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are looking to pull out employees that have at least two skills. If so, it looks like that's a simple aggregate query on table `EmployeeSkill`, like:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, COUNT(*)
FROM EmployeeSkill 
GROUP BY EmployeeID
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```